# Upload Conan packages from CI

Tags: conan

I run my own Conan server and want to automatically upload packages generated by CI. When I use `conan upload` it prompts me for a username and password. Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, therea are a couple of ways to do it:

- Using the command `conan user myuser -p mypassword` you can "log-in" into the remote, so the local cache will store a temporary token to authenticate against the server, and subsequent commands will not require it. Note that this token can expire, check the docs (e.g. for [conan_server](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/server.html#server-parameters)). Also, if you are managing more remotes, there is a login per remote (add `-r=myremote` to the above for each one
- There are environment variables you can use for this `CONAN_LOGIN_USERNAME, CONAN_PASSWORD` and with using `_REMOTENAME` for different remotes. Have a look [here in the docs](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-login-username-conan-login-username-remote-name). This is probably the way to go for CI, so the password is not plain text in the CI scripts. Some CI services will allow for encripted variables in the configuration. Furthermore, these variables allow automatically log-in in case of expired tokens, which can happen if they are set to short times, and the builds are very long.

Comment: It's `CONAN_PASSWORD` and not `CONAN_LOGIN_PASSWORD`. Otherwise, that worked.